# Which patterns should i use when i building wizard GUI (next, back, cancel)

Tags: design-patterns

help me here im drowning in switch / if / else hell ....
im trying to build wizard that hold allot of pages and states .
i have 5 main categories and in each category i have a wizard.
now im doing it with zillion switch's and if's there must be better way for that .
looking for design patterns

Comment: Accept previous answers.

Comment: Are you working in an object-oriented language?

Comment: yes c++ and Qt in win xp

Comment: can you give some trublemaking code pieces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its obvious - State

every your page can be treated as separated state

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

so you need state machine - some kind of:

page1 -> page2 -> page3 or page4 .... and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about a wizard as a set of commands. Each step configures a command, and the wizard executes all of them to achieve its goal.